# Difficulty Accessing Section of Website using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to access the calendar data on an airbnb listing and so far have been unsuccessful. I am using the Mechanize gem in Ruby, and when I try to access the link to access the table, I am encountering the following error:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page1=agent.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/726348")
page2=agent.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/calendar_tab_inner2/73944?cal_month=11&cal_year=2013&currency=USD")
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 400 => Net::HTTPBadRequest for https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/calendar_tab_inner2/726348?cal_month=11&cal_year=2013&currency=USD -- unhandled response
```

I have also tried to click on the tab that generates the table with the following code, but doing so simply generates the html from the original url.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page1=agent.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/726348")
page2=agent.click(page1.link_with(:href => '#calendar'))
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your `page2` link did not work for me. But this one did `https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/calendar_tab_inner2/726348?cal_month=11&cal_year=2013&currency=GBP`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either

Comment: that looks like you need something that can handle javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem, you need to check the request headers:

```
page = agent.get url, nil, nil,  {'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```